# Scheduled Spring MVC task not updating DB entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, asynchronous, scheduled-tasks

Good Morning,

I am trying to create a scheduled task which has to update database entity cyclically, I am using Spring MVC and Hibernate as ORM.

**Problem**

The scheduled task should update entities in background, but changes are not persisted in the Database.

**Structure of the system**

I have a `Batch` entity with basic information and plenty of sensors inserting record in the DB every few seconds.

Related to the `Batch` entity, there is a `TrackedBatch` entity which contains many calculated fields related to the `Batch` entity itself, the scheduled task takes each `Batch` one by one, update related data from sensors with `lotto = lottoService.updateBatchRelations(batch)` and then update the `TrackedBatch` entity with the new computed data.

A user can modify `Batch` basic information, then the system should recompute `TrackedBatch` data and update the entity (this is done by the controller which calls `updateBatchFollowingModification` method). This step is correctly done with an asynch method, the problem comes when the scheduled task should recompute the same infos.

**Asynch method used to update entities after user modification (Working correctly)**

```
@Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
@Transactional
public void updateBatchFollowingModification(Lotto lotto)
{
    logger.debug("Daemon started");
    Lotto batch = lottoService.findBatchById(lotto.getId_lotto(), false);
    lotto = lottoService.updateBatchRelations(batch);
    lotto.setTrackedBatch(trackableBatchService.modifyTrackedBatch(batch.getTrackedBatch(), batch));
    logger.debug("Daemon ended");
}
```

**Scheduled methods to update entities cyclically (Not working as expected)**

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
public void updateActiveBatchesWithDaemon()
{
    logger.info("updating active batches in background");

    List<Integer> idsOfActiveBatches = lottoService.findIdsOfActiveBatchesInAllSectors();
    if(!idsOfActiveBatches.isEmpty())
    {
        logger.info("found " + idsOfActiveBatches.size() + " active batches");
        for(Integer id : idsOfActiveBatches)
        {
            logger.debug("update batch " + id + " in background");
            updateBatch(id);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        logger.info("no active batches found");
    }
}

@Transactional
public void updateBatch(Integer id)
{
    Lotto activeLotto = lottoService.findBatchById(id, false);
    updateBatchFollowingModification(activeLotto);
}
```

As a premise, I can state that scheduled method is fired/configured correctly and runs continously (the same stands for asynch method, as following a user modification all entities are updated correctly), at line `updateBatchFollowingModification(activeLotto)` in `updateBatch` method, the related entities are modified correctly (even the `TrackedBatch`, I have checked with the debugger), then the changes are not persisted in the Database when method ends and no exception is thrown.

Looking around the internet I didn't find any solution to this problem nor it seems to be a known problem or bug from Hibernate and Spring.

Also reading Spring documentation about scheduling didn't help, I also tried to use `save` method in the scheduled task to save again the entity (but it obiously didn't work).

**Further considerations**

I do not know if the `@Scheduled` annotation needs some extra configuration to handle `@Transactional` methods as in the web devs are using those annotations together with no problem, moreover in documentation no cons are mentioned.

I also do not think it is a concurrency problem, because if the asynch method is modifying the data, the scheduled one should be stopped by the implicit optimistic locking system in order to finish after the first transaction commit, the same stands if the first to acquire the locking is the scheduled method (correct me if I am wrong).

I cannot figure out why changes are not persisted when the scheduled method is used, can someone link documentation or tutorials on this topic? so I can find a solution, or, better, if someone faced a similar problem, how it can be solved?

Comment: I can confirm that @ Scheduled works with @ Transactional methods without any special configuration, in Spring 2.2.6

Comment: I am using Spring MVC 5.2.5, but I think it is managed the same way, so there should be no problem on that side.

Comment: @Stomf  do you mean in spring 2.2.6 @ Transactional  method should not be in a seprate class ?

Comment: That sounds like a new question @zsh

Comment: @Stomf what i knew was that @ transactional and @ scheduled shoud be in seprate class to work fine. but here both annotations are in same method and problem solved by isolation level change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to resolve the issue by explicitly defining the isolation level for the transaction involved in the process and by eliminating the `updateBatch` method (as it was a kind of duplicated feature as `updateBatchFollowingModification` is doing the same thing), in particular I put the isolation level for `updateBatchFollowingModification` to `@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)`.

This obviously works in my case as no scalability is needed, so serializing actions do not bring any problem to the application.